# Is $\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb S^2$ homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^4$ with a line removed?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, metric-spaces

Can anyone please provide a reference or a proof of that the $\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb S^2$ space is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^4$ with a line $\Bbb R^1$ removed? Thank you!

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/526942/what-are-the-topological-properties-of-a-schwarzschild-black-hole-and-of-its-ho

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using $\Bbb S^2\subset \Bbb R^3$, we have the homeomorphism
$$\begin{align}\Bbb R\times \Bbb S^2&\to \Bbb R^3\setminus\text{pt}\\
(r,v)&\mapsto e^rv\end{align}$$
and from that and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3580481/272127) readily the desired result via the obvious
$$\Bbb R\times(\Bbb R^3\setminus\text{pt})\to \Bbb R^4 \setminus\text{line}$$