# What is the topology of the Galilean and Newtonian spacetimes?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

The definition of the Galilean spacetime is a [tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) $(\mathbb{R}^4,t_{ab},h^{ab},\nabla)$ where $t_{ab}$ (temporal metric) and $h^{ab}$ (spatial metric) are tensor fields and $\nabla$ is the coordinate derivative operator specifying the geodesic trajectories (see: [Spacetime Structure](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/11265/1/spacetimestructure.pdf)).

A single metric does not work, because the speed of light is infinite, so time and space should be treated separately with the temporal metric:

$$t_{ab}=(\text{d}_a t)(\text{d}_b t)$$

and the spatial metric:

$$h^{ab}=\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^a\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^b+
\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)^a\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)^b+
\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)^a\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)^b$$

Finally, $\nabla$ on $\mathbb{R}^4$
is a unique flat derivative operator that for each coordinate $x^i$ satisfies:

$$\nabla_a\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right)^b=\mathbf{0}$$

In turn, the Newtonian spacetime is the same tuple with an additional structure $(\mathbb{R}^4,t_{ab},h^{ab},\nabla,\lambda^a)$ where $\lambda^a$ is a field that adds the preferred frame of rest:

$$\lambda^a=\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)^a$$

> What is the topology of the Galilean and Newtonian spacetimes?

To clarify my question on an example, the Schwarzschild spacetime is defined by the following metric:

$$ {ds}^{2} = -\left(1 - \frac{r_\mathrm{s}}{r} \right) \,dt^2 + \left(1-\frac{r_\mathrm{s}}{r}\right)^{-1} \,dr^2 + r^2 d\Theta^2 $$

Where $d\Theta^2$ denotes the spherical metric induced by the Euclidean on a two sphere, i.e.

$$ d\Theta^2 = d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta \, d\varphi^2\;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\; r^2=\sum_{i=1}^3 dx_i^2 $$

According to [What is the topology of a Schwarzschild black hole?](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.5790) - the topology of the Schwarzschild spacetime is $\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb S^2$, which is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^4$ with the $r=0$  line removed (see: [Is $\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb S^2$ homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^4$ with a line removed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3521853/is-bbb-r2-times-bbb-s2-homeomorphic-to-bbb-r4-with-a-line-removed)).

Once again, the Schwarzschild spacetime is just an example to clarify the question, not a part of the question. Thank you!

Comment: Aside from your question, I argue that even $\mathbb R^4$ as an underlying set assumes too much structure, since $\mathbb R^4$ has a natural choice of origin, a natural vector space structure and even a natural choice of basis within that structure. (Non-Aristotelian) Spacetime does *not* have a privileged event, and is better described by means of the affine space $\mathbb A^4$.

Comment: @giobrach Good point. Thanks for your insight!

Comment: Isn't $\lambda^a$ redundant ? You could define a galilean frame of rest as any global map of spacetime where all Christoffel symbols are 0.

Comment: @V.Semeria I am not a mathematician, so I’ll try to answer your question intuitively. The Galilean spacetime is incompatible with the propagation of light described by the Maxwell equations. This is understood since light is inherently relativistic and requires the Minkowski spacetime. However, if you stay in a preferred frame and avoid coordinate transformations, you can sort of make mechanics and electromagnetism work together, as Newton did. So you are correct that the choice of a preferred frame is completely arbitrary, but the Newtonian spacetime requires this choice to be made upfront.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can give it whatever topology you want, but the most obvious and natural choice would just be the ordinary Euclidean topology of $\mathbb{R}^4$.  All the extra structure you are adding can be considered naturally as just extra structure on top of the usual smooth manifold structure of $\mathbb{R}^4$, which has the usual Euclidean topology.