# What is the topological space obtained by cutting $M\times N$ along a copy of $M$ or $N$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, surgery-theory

What is the topological space obtained by cutting $M\times N$ along a copy of $M$ or $N$ (both closed topological spaces). E.g. if we cut a torus $\Bbb S^1\times \Bbb S^1$ along a circle then the result is a cylinder.

If the answer depends on $M$ and $N$, the simple case $\Bbb S^n\times \Bbb S^m$ suffices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing a copy of $M$ from the product corresponds entirely to removing a point from $N$ before taking the product:
$$
(M\times N)\setminus(M\times \{p\})=M\times(N\setminus\{p\})
$$
In the case of $S^1\times S^1$, removing a point from a circle gives an interval, and a circle times an interval yields your cylinder.

Some times the result will depend on exactly which point you remove from $N$, of course. For instance, if you have a closed cylinder shell $S^1\times [0,1]$, then removing an end point from $[0,1]$ results in a half-open cylinder, while removing an interior point results in two half-open cylinders.

Comment: Thanks. But in Closed manifolds it is not important which point we are removing. Right?

Comment: @C.F.G. No, but in general topological spaces it is.

Comment: What if we remove just a point from a product? e.g. what is the result of $\Bbb S^3\times \Bbb S^3\setminus \{pt\}$?

Comment: @C.F.G The result of that is just $\Bbb S^3\times \Bbb S^3\setminus \{pt\}$. It's not a product space. In fact, here the analogy to regular _arithmetic product_ works nicely. Your original question is like comparing $nm - n$ to $n(m-1)$. They are equal. However, your current question is about $nm-1$, which doesn't factor in any nice way.

Comment: Thanks. So what is it topologically? for example, torus without a point is homotopic to wedge sum of two circles.

Comment: @C.F.G I think that depends on the space. But for $\Bbb S^m\times \Bbb S^n$, removing a point indeed gives you something homotopic to the corresponding wedge sum. Say we remove $(\text{north pole}, \text{north pole})$. Then the homotopy moves $(x,y)$ away from the removed point (each coordinate at a speed proportional to their original distance from the north pole) until one of the two coordinates hits the south pole of its sphere.